# Ruby on Rails - Accessing Referenced Join Table's object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**rating.rb**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vote
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course_textbook

  validates_presence_of :vote, :student
end
```

**course_textbook.rb**

```
class CourseTextbook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :textbook

  has_many :ratings

  validates_presence_of :course, :textbook
end
```

Is there a way to instead of going `rating.course_textbook.textbook` you go `rating.textbook`? Would I just make methods in the models? Or is there a way to make ActiveRecord do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with delegations:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    delegate :textbook, to: :course_textbook
end
```

Now you can call it like that:

```
rating.textbook
```

You can find more options for the `delegate`-Method here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#method-delegation

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I knew rails was going to have something for it. Thanks a bunch. I'll be sure to accept this answer when I'm allowed to.